# Aggregate by year, then by month, and day

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with dates in this format:

```js
{year: number, month: number, day: number}
```

I need to separate it into nested groups:

**Year ⇒ Month ⇒ Day**

The idea is to create a logic similar to a Timeline, but free to customize the view.

I tried to use MongoDB Aggregate:

```js
{ 
    _id : { 
    year : "$dShow.year", 
    //month : "$dShow.month",
    //day : "$dShow.day"
  },
  list: {
    $push: {
      _id: "$_id",
      forever: "$forever",
      text: "$text",
      status: "$status",
      recurrence: "$recurrence",
      title: "$title",
      dExpiration: "$dExpiration",
      ownerId: "$ownerId",
      dShow: "$dShow"
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to make the next step.

The desired output is something like this:

```js
[
    "years:" {
        "year": 2022,
        "list": [
            {
                "month": "jan",
                "list": [
                    {
                        "day": 13,
                        "list": [
                            {"dShow": {"year": 2022, "month": 1, "day": 13}, "title": "Title 1"}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "month": "feb",
                "list": [
                    {
                        "day": 24,
                        "list": [
                            {"dShow": {"year": 2022, "month": 2, "day": 24}, "title": "Another Title"}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

PS.: I also consider a pipe in Angular, if there is a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `dShow.year`, `dShow.month`, and `dShow.day`.
2. `$group` - Group by `_id.month` and `_id.day`.
3. `$group` - Group by `_id.year`.
4. `$project` - Decorate the output document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: "$dShow.year",
        month: "$dShow.month",
        day: "$dShow.day"
      },
      list: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: "$_id.year",
        month: "$_id.month"
      },
      list: {
        $push: {
          day: "$_id.day",
          list: "$list"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.year",
      list: {
        $push: {
          month: "$_id.month",
          list: "$list"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      year: "$_id",
      list: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ISIA_wqCS30)

If you want to group all the documents into one, you would need another `$group` with `_id: null`.

Comment: Stunning!
How would I sort all the lists in descendant order? (Sorry, forgot).

Comment: Use `$sort` stage and place as first stage before grouping. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GsDJdplsMb0)